# How can i use a Textbox, that was created programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-textbox

I'm trying to write a four-in-a-row game in WPF.

I want to programmatically insert textboxes, which are my gameboxes. It works now, but I don't know how to control them with a button afterwards because I can't use the names I assign them.

The goal is to change the background color of the textboxes after pressing a button.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int x = 100;
        int y = 190;

        for (int i = 1; i < 43; i++)
        {
            TextBox tbx = new TextBox();

            tbx.Name = "Field" + i;

            tbx.Height = tbx.Width = 50;
            tbx.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            tbx.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            tbx.Margin = new Thickness(x, y, 0, 0);
            myGrid.Children.Add(tbx);

            x += 55;

            if (i % 7 == 0)
            {
                y += 55;
                x = 100;
            }

        }
    }
```

[This is how it looks so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6KqF.png)

Comment: Store them in a `List<TextBox> _textBoxes` field in the class?

Comment: Or store them in a 2d array `a[(i-1)/7, (i-1)%7] = tbx;`

Comment: Integer division and modulo operations work best when numbering from 0 to N-1. If you started numbering `i` at 0, you could write `x = 100 + (i % 7) * 55; y = 190 + i/7 * 55;` and `a[i/7, i%7] = tbx;`. Then you can acces the textboxes with `a[col, row]` with both indexes ranging from 0 to 6.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I'm gonna go with this one, but how do I declare a. Sorry for the simple question, but i'm not that long into programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the text boxes in a 2d array. Use a class field:

```cs
private TextBox[,] textBoxes = new TextBox[7, 7];
```

Integer division and modulo operations work best when numbering from 0 to N-1. If you started numbering i at 0, you could write

```cs
x = 100 + (i % 7) * 55;
y = 190 + i / 7 * 55;
// and
textBoxes[i % 7, i / 7] = tbx;
```

Then you can access the textboxes with `textBoxes[column, row]` with both indexes ranging from 0 to 6.

---

But you could simply use nested for loops instead of doing any index calculations

```
for (int ix = 0; ix < 7; ix++) {
    for (int iy = 0; iy < 7; iy++) {
        int x = 100 + 55 * ix;
        int y = 190 + 55 * iy;

        var tbx = new TextBox();
        tbx.Height = tbx.Width = 50;
        tbx.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        tbx.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        tbx.Margin = new Thickness(x, y, 0, 0);

        myGrid.Children.Add(tbx);
        textBoxes[ix, iy] = tbx;
    }
}
```